# sql and c# - update if exists, else insert

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using MySqlCommand in MySqlConnection in a WinForms C# application to insert data into my database.

**NOTE: lets say ALL names are unique, no matter what!!**

how can I update a row if the column value in "name" already exists in database?

and if it does not exist, i want to insert new row.

Here is my code now:

```
command.CommandText = @"
    INSERT INTO users (name, age, job)
    VALUES (@name, @age, @job)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users SET age = @age, job = @job WHERE name = @name
";
```

I already set values to @name, @age and @job like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Users.Name);
```

I want to check, if `@name` already exists in the "name" column in the database. So if @name is "John", it should check if "John" already exists.

And if exists, I only want to update the age and job on that row.

And if "John" does not exist, insert the full row with name+age+job.

This code gives me an error like this:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE users SET age = 50, job =' at line 1

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests: *check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for [the right syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)*?

Comment: Yes, and I don't see where I did wrong in my code. i checked that 1000 times

Comment: Well you should have checked one more time. You are using the table name and a `SET` when you should not.

Comment: removed that, and still the same error. it is not updating in the database

Answer (score 1):

You have the update part your query wrong, it should just be:

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE age = @age, job = @job
```

Comment: but how would it know what to check? I want to check if the name exists. What if two people have the same age? wouldnt it update them then? i cant see how it would see if only the name exists... what the hell?

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, key's are unique. Since it already established that the key exists, it knows what record to update since there is only one.

Comment: This created duplicated names now.. :S Is it something I set in the database to "unique" or what? I dont get it

Comment: Do you have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE INDEX`on the field `name`?

Comment: in my database I have: id (AI) | name | age | job. i cant click "unique" on name.

Comment: In order for `ON DUPLICATE KEY` to work, there needs to be a conflict in either a `PRIMARY KEY` or an `UNIQUE INDEX` when the `INSERT` is attempted. If you cannot get the value for the `(AI)` column in your application to use in your query, you will have to `SELECT`, see if the name exists, then `UPDATE` or `INSERT` depending of if the name exists.

Comment: how do I set the primary key to the "name" column? I deleted the ID columns now. So now I only have: `name | age | job` in my database. None of them has the primary key icon next to them. I tried using: `ALTER TABLE users ADD PRIMARY KEY (name)` but that did not do anything?